# Create column for rolling total for the previous month of a current rows date

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

**Context**
Using Presto syntax, I'm trying to create an output table that has rolling totals of an 'amount' column value for each day in a month. In each row there will also be a column with a rolling total for the previous month, and also a column with the difference between the totals.

**Output Requirements**

1. completed: create `month_to_date_amount` column that stores rolling total from
   sum of `amount` column. The range for the rolling total is between 1st of month and current row `date` column value. Restart rolling
   total each month. 
   I already have a working query below that creates this column.

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(amount) OVER (
        PARTITION BY
            team,
            month_id
        ORDER BY
            date ASC
    ) month_to_date_amount
FROM (
    SELECT -- this subquery is required to handle duplicate dates
        date,
        SUM(amount) AS amount,
        team,
        month_id
    FROM input_table
    GROUP BY
        date,
        team,
        month_id
) AS t
```

2. create `prev_month_to_date_amount` column that:

   a. stores previous months rolling amount for the current rows `date` and `team` and add to same
   output row.

   b. Return `0` if there is no record matching the previous month date. (Ex. Prev months date for March 31 is Feb 31 so does not exist). Also a record will not exist for days that have no `amount` values. Example output table is below.
3. create `movement` column that stores the difference
   amount between `month_to_date_amount` column and
   `prev_month_to_date_amount` column from current row.

### Question

Could someone assist with my 2nd and 3rd requirements above to achieve my desired output shown below? By either adding on to my current query above, or creating another more efficient one if necessary. A solution with multiple queries is fine.

#### Input Table

| team | date | amount | month_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-04-01 | 1 | 2022-04 |
| A | 2022-04-01 | 1 | 2022-04 |
| A | 2022-04-02 | 1 | 2022-04 |
| B | 2022-04-01 | 3 | 2022-04 |
| B | 2022-04-02 | 3 | 2022-04 |
| B | 2022-05-01 | 4 | 2022-05 |
| B | 2022-05-02 | 4 | 2022-05 |
| C | 2022-05-01 | 1 | 2022-05 |
| C | 2022-05-02 | 1 | 2022-05 |
| C | 2022-06-01 | 5 | 2022-06 |
| C | 2022-06-02 | 5 | 2022-06 |

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate dates. Can you provide some data regarding the same?

Comment: Your query has partitioning by team for month_to_date_amount, while `prev_month_to_date_amount` seems to ignore partitioning by team. Is it correct?

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, the `prev_month_to_date_amount` should also be partitioned by team. Thx for catching this. I am currently revising the example table to reflect this.

Comment: Hi @NishantGupta, I added an example duplicate row to the input table at the first row.

Comment: In Trino you could try to implement something like this using window functions due to [full range support](https://trino.io/blog/2021/03/10/introducing-new-window-features.html) but in presto I'm afraid you will need to look into some joins.

Comment: Thx @GuruStron. A solution with multiple queries using joins would work for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a good example of using the window function LAG.  In summary the query partitions the data by Team and Day of Month, and uses LAG to get the previous months amount and calculate the movement value.

e.g. for Team B data. The window function will create two partition sets: one with the Team B 01/04/2022 and 01/05/2022 rows, and one with the Team B 02/04/2022 and 02/05/2022 rows, order each partition set by date. Then for each set for each row, use LAG to get the data from the previous row (if one exists) to enable calculation of the movement and retrieve the previous months amount.

I hope this helps.

```
;with
totals
as
( 
  select
   *,
   sum(amount) over(
        partition by team, month_id 
         order by date, team) monthToDateAmount
  from
   ( select 
        date,
        sum(amount) as amount,
        team,
        month_id
    from input_table
    group by
        date,
        team,
        month_id
    ) as x
),
totalsWithMovement
as
(
select
  *,
  monthToDateAmount
    - coalesce(lag(monthToDateAmount) over(
          partition by team,day(date(date))
          order by team, date),0) 
      as movement,
  coalesce(lag(monthToDateAmount) over
        (partition by team, day(date(date)) 
        order by team,month_id),0) 
  as prevMonthToDateAmount
from
  totals
)
select
  date, amount, team, monthToDateAmount,
            prevMonthToDateAmount, movement  
from
  totalswithmovement
order by
  team, date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Stewart, however, the query required will need to use Presto syntax and I'm not sure this will convert. I tagged this question with presto but I should have been clearer in my summary. Also there would be no records with `0` `amount` values. There will not be a record matching the previous month date for the following cases. (1. previous day doesn't exist: Ex. Prev months date for March 31 is Feb 31 so prev record does not exist here), (2. a record will not exist for days that have no amount values)

Comment: That's okay for my time.  I was looking to solve an interesting SQL problem for practice.   Presto does appear to have a window function LAG method, and supports CTEs., and similar date functions. I think my current script should work with a few small tweaks.  If  there's no correct answer tomorrow morning (it's my bedtime now), I see if I can solve 1 & 2 above and get it running in Presto. Does Presto have an online Fiddler?

Comment: In regards to the Presto syntax, sorry I got ahead of myself in my original reply. I got the query to run afterwards without much issue. I couldn't find a Presto fiddle but as you were saying it looks like there's not many syntax changes. I only needed to convert `datepart(day,date)` to `DAY(date(date))` for presto. I'll review how it's handling the above edge cases 1 & 2 in the morning as well. Thanks again.

Comment: I've just given the existing sql a quick test and it appears to cover 1 & 2 already without any changes.   It just returns NULL for movement and prevMonth if there's no match.  So I was a bit hasty with my caveat, it was late at night.

Comment: I've updated the script  with the correct Presto DAY function.

Comment: Just updated again to add coalesce on the lag calls to remove the null values in the results

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Stewart. You've provided a working solution to my problem.

Comment: Hi Stewart, could you share how the Partition by `day(date(date))` works when there isn't a 'day' column? Is this somehow partitioning by the `date` column but just using the day?

Comment: That's right it's partitioning just using the day..  e.g. for Team B. It will create two partitions sets: one for day 1, and one for day 2 with two rows in each, order each partition set by date.  Then for each set for each row, get the data from the previous row (if one exists) .

Comment: Thanks Stewart. When validating data I'm discovering cases where the`prevMonthToDateAmount` is retrieved from 2 months before instead of the expected 1 month before when the previous month doesn't have a matching day. For example April doesn’t have 31st day, so  2022-05-31 (May 31) retrieves the `prevMonthToDateAmount` from 2022-03-31(March 31). Do you know if there is an easy solution for this by chance?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, if you read it, since I realised that wouldn't work  
I think a solution  would to ensure there's an entry for each team/date combination in the data source used by the  query.
You could fill in the gaps by generating all the dates in the range you're looking at. (maybe using a recursive CTE)  then cross join the dates with the list of unique teams.    Then do a difference between this date data and your source data on team and date to find the team/date combinations without an entry.   That sound complicated, but should be an easy solution.

Comment: I'm off out now for a couple of hours.   I'll  have quick look for ten minutes when I return to see if I can revised the query accordingly.   Unless you want to try yourself in the mean time,

Comment: It looks like I'm getting my desired output so far by updating the lag column to: 
 LAG(monthToDateAmount,  DAY(last_day_of_month(date(date) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH))  ) OVER ( PARTITION BY team ORDER BY
        month_id,
        team,
        DAY(date(date))
)

Comment: Nice one.  I didn't  consider doing it that way.